# Why ElasticSearch High Level Rest Client always returning aggregation name with type information

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-6

I have been trying to get elasticsearch aggregations using Java High-Level Rest Client. It is always returning aggregation name with type information, for example if I have given a "terms" aggregation with name "message", the response contains the returning aggregation name as "sterms#message" which is not expected unless the user specifically asks for type information. In ElasticSearch documentation ([Returning the type of the aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/returning-aggregation-type.html)), it is mentioned that if you don't pass "typed_keys" parameter, aggregation will return with the default name, but it is not happening while using java high level rest client. While I was debugging that, I found there is no "typed_keys" check is being performed while writing the key name and aggregation name always has "type#aggregation_name". How can, I stop getting the type name in aggregation names.

The class where this default functionality is written is ([ParsedAggregation.java](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/6.2/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/search/aggregations/ParsedAggregation.java)) at line 64.